# Websockets and Fandjango

Tags: django, facebook, websocket

I want to develop a Facebook application using Django==1.6 and Fandjando==4.2.

My game must have a real-time entry point, since it will be a real-time app (will be a MMO game).

Since I'm using Fandjango, the normal approach is to have:

```
@facebook_authorization_required
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    #processing and return
    return HttpResponse(bla, bla, bla)
```

This approach has two points:

1. It requires a middleware to be installed (Normal Fandjango lifecycle requires `fandjango.middlewares.FacebookMiddleware` to be installed).
2. It redirects to a custom `fandjango` view which generates HTML redirecting to facebook authorization page (using a 401 status code).

So, for JSON (ajax) entry points, I created a custom decorator (which works) which basically creates a wrapped view like this:

```
def fb_auth_ajax(view):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if (getattr(request, 'facebook', False) and getattr(request.facebook, 'user', False)):
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return JSONResponse(content={'error': 'Must authorize'}, status=401)
    return wrapper
```

And use it like:

```
@fb_auth_ajax
def view(request):
    return JSONResponse({'hello':'world'})
```

Currently, that approach works perfectly.

**WHAT I NEED** comes here: I want a Websocket entry point.

**What's the catch?**: I need the websocket be authenticated with Facebook. This means: I need the same logic. I need this logic:

```
Given a normal HTTP request.
if request.facebook exists and request.facebook.user:
    start a websocket (via protocol switch / upgrade)
else:
    return a 401
```

So I'll end using the same decorator.

But I need that such view:

1. start a websocket. start it via http upgrade. this is because I need the status=101 scenario, or status=401 scenario.
2. start it in the django-way. this is because I need the http request (`request`) have the `facebook` and `facebook.user` existing, and that's accomplished in the `fandjango.middlewares.FacebookMiddleware` (fandjango). this excludes websocket implementations based on tornadio, since:

   a. such websockets are outside of facebook, so they don't go through the middlewares.
    b. I don't expect to be allowed to expose two different servers.

**Question**: How could I accomplish it? What library could I use, which integrates Websockets in normal django views?

Answer (score 0):

[This library](https://bitbucket.org/schinckel/django-gevent-websocket/src) actually creates a websocket in a django view, althought the view is reached via another server instance as per documentation. The documentation is in the library repository itself. It requires you to declare:

```
@websocket
def view(request, websocket, ...):
    pass
```

AND you DONT have to return any type of response at all. It is forbidden in the protocol. If you want to terminate a connection use:

```
websocket.close(integerCode, textMessage)
```

according to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent). If you don't explicitly call close(), close() will be called with integer code 1006 (abnormal termination).

However, this library has some issues.